# Data missing while Reading Excel sheet using OleDbConnection in C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

I need to read the excel data and store in database.
when I try to read the data, there are some data got missed, I couldn't able to find.

It's my excel sheet
[image]

My code :

```
private string Excel03ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";

 [![//Get the name of the First Sheet.
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows\[0\]\["TABLE_NAME"\].ToString();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            //Read Data from the First Sheet.
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {

                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From \[" + sheetName + "\]";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
                        con.Close();

                        //Populate DataGridView.
                        //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }

            dtExcelData = dtExcelData.AsEnumerable().Skip(2).Take(1).CopyToDataTable();

            return dtExcelData;][2]][2]
```

Data after reading through in oledbConnection :

[image]

Comment: King, do you want to read all data (including headers) or do you want to get only data (without headers)?

Comment: Hi Mac,how are you, data is enough. Now it is working, after I  set IMEX=1 in  connection

Comment: Hi King! Using IMEX=1 is good practice, but you have to define the range you want to read. Please refer [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Answer (score 1):

You have some merged cell in your excel Sheet , it's better to access your cells directly

I think here also can help you:

[Excel - Reading Merged Cells (rows) in .NET using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193033/excel-reading-merged-cells-rows-in-net-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to your project easily;
https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/